# How to make programs talk to each other

Tags: python-3.x, server, ipc

I'd like to write a **Python 3** program which simulates playing a game, e.g. chess. The program should then be played by both AI bots and humans. The setup should be something like: A program, called `game-server` which, once started, runs until stopped. Another program `game-client`, which is the user interface to the bot or human. A typical game with players could be like:

```

```
$ game-server --start
$ game-client --user A --get-current-position
$ game-client --user A --do <sample move>
$ game-client --user B --get-current-position
$ game-client --user B --do <another sample move>
```

```

**It should be possible to play the game remotely.**

My questions are:

1. Is there any canonical, i.e. generally accepted, way to implement this type of functionality? If so, what is it?
2. I thought of using maybe Django as a web framework. Is there any difference for the implementation if the game is to be played just locally? I'm really looking for a way to enable two different processes to talk to each other.
3. How about 2 or more "servers". I'm talking about programs, which generally run like forever, do their job, and once in a while have to "talk" to other programs, like persons in real life. How to implement such a situation. Is a http or port approach the best one?

I'd really be happy at any answer. I tried to google it, but I don't really know, where to start.

Comment: It sounds like you need to start a bit earlier and learn some more basic programming principles and techniques then you'll understand more about how to do this. What you're asking is no small task (game development). I'm not quite sure why you'd want to play a game by command line like that though.

Comment: @NotoriousPyro: Thanks for your answer. I'm planning to train an AI bot, and the command line is the simplest implementation I could think of. 
What kind of book or tutorial can you recommend for me? I just went through 6.00 from ocw.mit.edu

Comment: Using command line is no simpler than accepting user input from the console, and you'd avoid having to set up a connection on each move. You could then avoid having a server and use a direct connection instead. I would recommend starting on several popular  programming languages such as php, bash, Javascript, and then move onto more advanced ones. Start by bug fixing and customising others works to get a feel for how the code operates.